# Crack in acrylic bath tub, but fiberglass is ok

Tags: repair, bathtub, crack, fiberglass

I managed put a small crack in the corner of my acrylic bathtub. Looking underneath it looks like the crack is just to the acrylic, and the fiberglass shell is still in-tact.

Is this enough to hold water? Looking online, the fiberglass does the heavy lifting - but didn't want it to start leaking! I'll repair the cracked acrylic at a later point.

Comment: I expect it is polyester ,not acrylic.. It would be a problem if water has already gotten into the Fiberglas.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. Without more info, all we could say was "maybe." And, you should probably [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know how best to participate here.

Comment: Acrylic tubs do crack and if not sealed a blister will form and get worse and your tub can be ruined. It is very difficult to match, I have seen acrylic tubs crack because they were not properly bedded and the flex caused the crack.